# very touchy onmouseout behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to design something similar to what can be seen on http://www.thedana.com/ by the "Check availability" button - I've used the jquery.js file from w3school.com and got the following so far: http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/ (Book Now tab). Now as you realize, it is very touchy and fades out sometimes when it shouldn't (when the cursor is still in the middle of the field) how can I make this nicer, more user friendly?

Thanks!
Ron

Update:
I tried to implement that but it doesn't quite work as I would like to show my "fade" div upon hovering over "book" and keep it up as the cursor moves down, over "fade" how do I accomplish this?
Url:http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `div#fade` inside of the `div#book`, that will solve half of your problems. You will have to adapt the CSS as well for this change.

Another very important point to learners is that jQuery provides unobtrusive cross-browser event listeners attaching. That means, inline JS in the html as `onmouseenter="handler()"` is not just unnecessary and technically ugly - mixed structure with behavior -, it also pollutes the global scope with function names.

That's one of the reasons [people](http://w3fools.com/) advertise against W3School.

But back on topic here's a solution using the [DOM Ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and a [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) one:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bk97b/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="book">
    <a href="/drupal-7.14//?q=book">Book Now</a>
    <div id="fade">TEST</div>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
​$(function() {
    var fade = $('#fade');
    $('#book').hover(function() {
        fade.fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        fade.fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Again, you will have to rework the CSS removing the `position:absolute` and margins from `#fade`.

Comment: Thanks Fabricio that seems to work in general but if I keep my cursor in the let's say top 1/3rd of the dro down, the div fades out and disappears again, why would that be? :o

Comment: In my fiddle or did you implement it in your page yet? Can't seem to reproduce it in the fiddle. Check if there aren't any other mouseout/mouseover functions conflicting if it's in your page. `:P`

Comment: @cerr You have a `div#top` in your page which due to having `position:relative` is placed above the `div#fade`. Try removing the `position:relative` from it.

Comment: After you fix that, seems like FF has a bug with select elements inside of it. Little too sleepy to review that atm but best of luck man.

Comment: Maybe if you upgrade from jQuery 1.4.4 to 1.8.2 it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the fade looks good on my side, Linux Chrome and FF 15.0.1 but one thing, as soon as I want to select something from any drop down list, the box fades out... :( almost tho! :) Thanks Fabricio!

Comment: The `#top`'s CSS still has `position:relative` which places it above the `#fade`, also don't forget to remove the `http://quaaoutlodge.com/drupal-7.14/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4` which drupal includes when you upgrade to version 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with jquery's .mouseleave instead of the generic onmouseout?

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

"The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not the Inner element."